# Get Security Context of IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, webforms

Does anybody know how to get the security context that an IIS server is running in programmatically? This equates to the context that the connection pool is running in when a custom user is selected. I am having login problems accessing a database in a web application using integrated security but I do not have access to the IIS server itself and I would dearly like to log the username that it is using to set up the connection with the SQL server. There are plenty of articles on finding the username of user that is accessing the web application but I haven't found any about accessing the username of the context in which the IIS server itself is running.

Comment: You often don't even need any runtime logging but to determine the actual identity used to connect to database just based on configuration. I wrote some hints in https://halfblood.pro/the-basic-facts-about-iis-asp-net-process-thread-identities-835eaac876a0

Comment: About using integrated security asp.net to connect to sql server and get username, this link may be of some help to you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1003526/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-using-integrated-secu.html